# Why is swagger-maven-plugin complaining about a missing "locations" list"

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I support a platform used by a hundred or so SpringBoot services, along with a common build architecture.

I was working on a problem with our definition of the swagger-maven-plugin in our parent pom, but I discovered that I simply couldn't get a "simple" swagger plugin usage to work.  The plugin is complaining about a missing "locations" list, but as far as I can tell, I'm specifying that list exactly where it's supposed to be.

This is my current plugin def, with some minor renaming:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.8</version>
      <configuration>
        <apiSources>
          <apiSource>
            <locations>
                <location>com.company.platformpilot.resource</location>
            </locations>
            <basePath>/msapi/example/v1</basePath>
            <info>
              <title>Example Service</title>
              <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </info>
            <swaggerDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF/resources/example/swagger</swaggerDirectory>
            <outputPath>${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF/resources/example/swagger</outputPath>
          </apiSource>
        </apiSources>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

When I run this, it fails with the following:

```
16:34:40 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.kongchen:swagger-maven-plugin:3.1.8:generate (default) on project ExampleMs: <locations> is required by this plugin. -> [Help 1]
```